# Can't set all parameters in usbfilter with vagrant on virtualbox

Tags: virtualbox, vagrant

I've only been using vagrant for a month or 2, but am running into an issue with the usbfilter parameter setting. I'm trying to set the product. I can successfully set other options (say the productid, name, etc) but I can't seem to get the product to take. If I hand edit the parameter in virtualbox after building the vm, everything is fine. But I'm trying to avoid any hand editing of paramters.

Here is what I have in my Vagrant file:

```
# Implement determined configuration attributes
config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
  vb.customize ["usbfilter", "add", "0",
      "--target", :id,
      "--product", "PSSD T7",
      "--productid", "4001",
      "--name", "Samsung PSSD T7 [0100]"]
end
```

And here is what results after the VM is built:

[image: image of virtualbox USB filter settings that the above Vagrantfile creates]

Does anyone have any idea what is going on? Why can't I set the Product?

I'm running virtualbox 7.0.10, vagrant 2.3.7 and ubuntu 18.04 LTS. (I've tried these without success: hashicorp/bionic64, ubuntu/bionic64, ubuntu/focal64)